# reference dynamic Raphael object

Tags: jquery, raphael, custom-data-attribute

I am having trouble finding a solution to the following problem. I would like to reference a Raphael shape that has been created on the fly. Is it possible to use the jQuery find() function on the Raphael dom.node data

```
$.each(count, function(i, feed){
    var against = feed.against;
    var country = feed.country;
    var x = feed.lat;
    var y = feed.long;
    feed = R.rect(500-(y*3), 500-(x*3),50, 50).attr("fill","rgba(0,0,0,.4)").attr("stroke", "rgba(0,0,0,0)").data("country", country).data("against", against);
    $(feed[0]).hover(function() {
    feed.attr("fill","#FFF");

        var against = feed.data('against');
```

// here is it possible to do a jQuery style find() on elements with a specific data attr?

```
    },function() {
        feed.attr("fill","#000");    
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some corrections that needs to be done, for this. The below listing is the corrected code.
    I haven't checked the code.

```
$(feed[0]).hover(function() {
        var dthis = $(this), against = dthis.data('against');
        dthis.attr("fill","#FFF");
        // here is it possible to do a jQuery style find() on elements with a specific data attr?
        if(against && against == 'some_Speficic_value'){
            // do some thing on dthis
        }
    },function() {
        var dthis = $(this);
        dthis.attr("fill","#000");    
    });
```